# Объясните особенности перегрузки операторов в С++

Tags: c++

```
class Integer
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Integer(int i): value(i) 
    {}
    const Integer operator+(const Integer& rv) const {
        return (value + rv.value);
    }
};
```

Возьмём за основу этот код. И вот вопросы:
1. Почему возвращаемое значение не является ссылкой? Разве не рациональнее было бы написать const Integer&... 
2. Что означает, что возвращаемое значение является const? Что в данном случае я не смогу поменять с возвращаемым объектом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Почему возвращаемое значение не является ссылкой? Разве не рациональнее было бы написать const Integer&...

Встречный вопрос: а ссылку на что вы будете возвращать? Результатом операции сложения левого и правого операнда является новый объект. Его вы и возвращаете. В данном месте просто семантика говорит возвращать объект, а не ссылку на него. А дальше... Скорее всего сработает оптимизация VRO и лишних конструкторов/копирований вызываться не будет.

> 2. Что означает, что возвращаемое значение является const? Что в данном случае я не смогу поменять с возвращаемым объектом?

Нет. Нужно спрашивать дизайнера класса. Скорее всего сделано, дабы нельзя было у временного объекта вызвать неконтантные методы, например в таком случае:

```
Integer a{1};
Integer b{2};
(a + b).someMethod();
// или
(a + b)++; // при наличии реализации operator++ в постфиксной форме
```

Если метод `someMethod()` будет без квалификатора `const`, то, с точки зрения дизайна, он может изменить состояние класса и с данной реализацией будет ошибка компиляции. Поиграться можно тут: http://ideone.com/6ILKdJ

Просто присваивание создаст "копию" и константность на вас никак не повлияет: вы уже будете работать с другим объектом, т.е. в код ниже абсолютно легитимен:

```
Integer a{1};
Integer b{2};
Integer c = a + b
c++; // при наличии реализации operator++ в постфиксной форме
```

Хотя возможно, что это просто результат копипасты.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую ответить:

1. Если сделать возвращаемое значение ссылкой, возвращается ссылка на временный объект, что недопустимо.
2. Это означает именно то, что и должно - возвращаемый объект будет считаться неизменяемым и для него можно будет вызывать только методы, которые не меняют его состояние (модификатор const после списка аргументов в объявлении)